# Help identifying pinout of LTM-0436M multi-segment LED

Tags: led, pinout

I've got following unique segmented LED display module from local store. It has 8-pin (physically similar to common 7-Segment display), the marking on body of the module is clearly printed as "LTM-0436M", thus it seems a LED display module produced by Lite On Inc. Its display is driven by built-in PTC PT6961 IC (a LED Driver IC), so it's clear from PT696 datasheet how to drive the display, if only we know which pin of the module is connected to which pin of the controller IC.

[image: LTM-0436M Snapshot Pic]

The problem is, I have no idea about the pin configuration of this module. And since it's command-driven, I can't simply connect +3V/GND wires to test the pins (they are not simple anode/cathode terminals).

I've search [Lite On Inc. website](http://optoelectronics.liteon.com/en-global/led/LED-Component/index/4) with no luck (their website seems incomplete, a lot of product pages remains empty), the product (LTM-0436M) is not even listed. I've also tried google with any possible search keyword I can imagine, also with no luck.

The PT6961 itself requires 4 serial input pins for interfacing (Din, Dout, Clock, and Strobe) plus 3 input pins for key scanning (K1-3). It also needs to be connected with an external oscillator which I believe has been there inside the module (it's resin-protected, so it's impossible to see the inside without damaging it), so no need to break this pin out. Other than 4+3 input pins, this module needs power supply (VDD) and ground (GND) for total 9 pins, but it only has 8 pins.

Do any of you have experience with this module? Thanks in advance for your care.

Comment: It may be custom. Have you tried e-mailing lite-on?

Comment: @Connor Wolf: I've tried the 'Contact Us' web form from their website, it doesn't working (form can't be submitted), perhaps due to scripting error.

Comment: They must have an actual e-mail somewhere.

Comment: What's the name of the store you bought it from? Have you tried asking them who their supplier is?

Comment: You have the PT6961 datasheet, so you are in good shape. Carefully scrape the epoxy from the IC pins, then
test module pins for continuity to known pins on the PT691.